# My application is crashing and all I am getting is : -[UIImageView startAnimating] + 560 crash

Tags: ios, crash

My application is crashing and I am not getting location where it is crashing or what might have cause the crash.I have attached the crash report below.

```
Crashed: Thread
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x33f0 objc_retain + 16
1  UIKitCore                      0x62b358 -[UIImageView startAnimating] + 560
2  UIKitCore                      0x3bc5d0 -[UIActivityIndicatorView startAnimating] + 52
3  Foundation                     0x683fc <redacted> + 808
4  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x19a4 _pthread_start + 148
5  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0xea0 thread_start + 8
```

Comment: It would help if you could provide a code snippet from the relevant place in your code. From what you have provided, it is related to some animation happening on an UIImageView.

Comment: The `UIImageView` is internal, I guess the thing happening is animating a `UIActivityIndicatorView`, but @tomerpacific is right: Show us the code please. If you don't know what code exactly causes the crash (which is hard to imagine, because Xcode always pauses there and you can navigate by the crash stack trace lines), try to look at places that are expected to start a `UIActivityIndicatorView` at the moment of crashing. As a random guess of the crash reason, you might call the `startAnimating` method not from the main thread.